# How do I add "123" to the beginning of a string and pad it to be exactly 12 chars?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I need to add "123" and zeros for any string - but the resulting string must be exactly 12 characters long.

For example:

```
28431 = 123000028431
987   = 123000000987
2     = 123000000002
```

How to do this in C#?

Comment: What happnes when the input length > 9

Comment: by the way, add a tag as homework xD

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
string result = "123" + text.PadLeft(9, '0');
```

In other words, split the task in half - one part generating the "000028431", "000000987" etc part using [`string.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx), and the other prefixing the result with "123" using simple string concatenation.

There are no doubt more efficient approaches, but this is what I'd do unless I had a good reason to believe that efficiency was really important for this task.

Comment: Lol, I was about to ask you how efficient that approach was, I guess it's only going to be called once or twice so doesn't really matter. :)

Comment: I bet that there are a dozen other places in any application which will be more ineffecient than this code snippet.

Answer (score 17):

```
var result = string.Format("123{0}", number.PadLeft(9, '0'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
var str = String.Format("123{0:0#########}", 28431);
```

or

```
var str = String.Format("123{0:000000000}", 28431);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have numbers less than 1000000000, you could just add 123000000000 to each number.

Comment: The values are `string`s, not a numeric type.

Comment: Ah... ok... I just assumed they were numeric since that was what the examples were.  Looks like there are other good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming...

1. The strings are known to always contain representations of decimal integers.
2. The represented integer is always less than 10<sup>9</sup>.

...you could do this:

```
(123000000000 + long.Parse(s)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
            string argString ="28431 ";

            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(argString);
            for (int i =  12 -argString.Length-3; i >0 ; i--)
            {
                 sb.Insert(0, "0");              
            }

            string result = string.Format("123{0}",sb.ToString());
```